# awk + set external var in awk

Tags: linux, awk

the following awk syntax cut the lines from the file

from the line that have **port XNT1**

until  **END OF COMMAND** line

```
 #  awk '/\/stats\/port XNT1\/if/,/END OF COMMAND/' /var/tmp/test 

  >> SW_02_03 - Main# /stats/port XNT1/if
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  Interface statistics for port XNT1:
  IBP/CBP Discards:                  0
  L3 Discards:                       0


  >> SW_02_03 - Port Statistics# END OF COMMAND
  # 
  # 
  #
```

now I set external variable as  XNTF=XNT1 in awk command

but from some reason XNTF in the awk not get the "XNT1" value , and awk not display the lines!!!!!!!!

```
  #  awk -v XNTF=XNT1 '/\/stats\/port XNTF\/if/,/END OF COMMAND/' /var/tmp/test
```

please advice why awk not works when I set external variable ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `//`, variables are not expanded. You'll have to use the `~` operator to match against an assembled regex:

```
awk -v XNTF=XNT1 '$0 ~ "/stats/port " XNTF "/if",/END OF COMMAND/' /var/tmp/test
```

Generally, `$0 ~ some_string` matches `$0` (the line) against `some_string` interpreted as a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I normally try to avoid the range command in `awk` `,`, since it not so flexible.  This should do:

```
awk -v XNTF=XNT1 '$0~"/stats/port " XNTF "/if" {f=1} f; /END OF COMMAND/ {f=0}' file
 >> SW_02_03 - Main# /stats/port XNT1/if
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  Interface statistics for port XNT1:
  IBP/CBP Discards:                  0
  L3 Discards:                       0


  >> SW_02_03 - Port Statistics# END OF COMMAND
```